# Changing output directory of library created through pybind11_add_module

Tags: python, cmake, pybind11

I am using CMake to build some python bindings for my code using Pybind11. It is working well, but they get compiled in the main `build` directory. I would like them to be built on `build\python` directory. I am trying the following:

```
pybind11_add_module(myModule src/main.cpp)
set_target_properties(myModule PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python")
```

But it is not working as intended, `myModule` is still built on the `build` directory as if the `set_target_properties` was not being called.

In the official `pybind11_add_module` documentation it is written:

> This function behaves very much like CMake’s builtin add_library (in fact, it’s a wrapper function around that command). It will add a library target called  to be built from the listed source files. In addition, it will take care of all the Python-specific compiler and linker flags as well as the OS- and Python-version-specific file extension. The produced target  can be further manipulated with regular CMake commands.

So I assumed that `set_target_properties` could be used to indicate a different output directory after it, is this not the case? If not, how can this be done?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Property `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` affects on `dll` libraries on Windows. For `.so` libraries you need to use `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property.

Comment: Thanks!! That was it, can't believe I missed that in the docs. If you want to add it as an answer I will gladly mark it as solved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pybind11` module is a library of either a SHARED or MODULE type.

Build directory for SHARED libraries is specified via `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` on all platforms except for Windows (and its `dll`'s).

Build directory for MODULE libraries is specified via `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` on all platforms without exception.

Detailed description of types for output artifacts in CMake and corresponded `OUTPUT` variables can be found in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#output-artifacts).